# Is it safe to use Doctrine magic "findby" methods for production? Or are they only for prototyping?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I'm using in many places, Doctrine magic methods like below

```
Doctrine::getTable('User')->findByUserid(id);
```

Is it recommended to get data like this or should this be replaced with queries?

Also, are there any recommended settings in general when using Doctrine + CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you check the Doctrine [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php) you will see that it's just a method forwarder. If you prefer you can just replace the magic methods with static ones- but I guess the performance advantage would be negligible.